# how to use Filezilla via python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, filezilla

I need to download lots of data (around 30 GB every day, of which some files are > 1GB). For large files in particular, the speed when I download via FileZilla is an order of magnitude (almost 10x) faster than if I manually download (right-click and save in Windows) or if I download via Python 3.3.

My python 3.3 script given below recursively loops through directories on an FTP site and downloads a file only if that file hasn't already been downloaded (it is modified version of a two different posts on this forum). I would like to replace Python 3.3's native ftplib (in the code below) to use FileZilla.

```
import ftplib
import os

def traverseFTP(ftpObj,depth,cdir,bdir):
    # print(depth)
    if depth>10:
        return []
    else:
        # do the following
        data=[]
        ftpObj.dir(data.append)
        for entry in data:
            # dName=entry[55:len(entry)].strip()
            dName=entry.split()[-1]
            dIsDir=entry[0]
            if dName!="." and dName!="..":
                if dIsDir!="d":
                    # download if not already downloaded
                    dFullName=bdir+cdir+"\\"+dName
                    if not os.path.isfile(dFullName):
                        print("... Downloading ",dName)
                        if not os.path.isdir(bdir+cdir): os.makedirs(bdir+cdir)
                        ftpObj.retrbinary('RETR %s' % dName,open(dFullName,'wb').write)
                else:
                    ftpObj.cwd(dName)
                    cdir1=cdir+"\\"+dName
                    print("\nEntering ",cdir1)
                    traverseFTP(ftpObj,depth+1,cdir1,bdir)
                    ftpObj.cwd("..")
                    print("Exiting ",cdir1)

def ftpInitialize(ftpHost,userID,userPW):
    ftpObj=ftplib.FTP(ftpHost)
    ftpObj.login(user=userID,passwd=userPW)
    return ftpObj

def main():
    ftpHost="hostname"
    userID="userlogin"
    userPW="userpassword"
    targetDir="D:\\LocalDir"
    ftpObj=ftplib.FTP(ftpHost)
    ftpObj.login(user=userID,passwd=userPW)
    traverseFTP(ftpObj,0,"",targetDir)
    ftpObj.quit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Please note: Please consider me a Python beginner (so detailed answers will be much appreciated).

Also, is there any limitation on File Size (of the downloaded file) in ftplib of Python 3.3? My code gets hanged up usually on sizes > 0.5 GB, but works fine on sizes < 0.5 GB. I am using WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.1 distribution (i.e. 64-bit) on a 64-bit Windows 7 pc.

Comment: probably, the reason that Filezilla is transfering faster is that it's using seperate threads for files. Instead of downloading one file at a time in sequence, it's able to download several at once. You too could implement `threading` in your application using a `ThreadPool`.